# Inserting data from one BigQuery table to another returns 0 rows on group by

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to do insert data from one BigQuery table to another by running the query shown below but I get 0 rows in return. However if I take out the `Survey` column, I get the correct number of rows in return.

Both the nested fields have the same type of schema. I have checked and double checked the column names too but can´t seem to figure out what´s wrong with `Survey` field.

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
(
  Title, Description, Address, Survey
)
SELECT
  Title as Title,
  Description as Description,
  
  [STRUCT(
         ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Address_Instance.Field1, Address_Instance.Field2)) AS Address_Record 
  )]
  as Address,
  
  [STRUCT(
         ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Survey_Instance.Field1, Survey_Instance.Field2)) AS Survey_Record
  )]
  as Survey
  
FROM
   source_table,
   UNNEST(Survey) AS Survey,
   UNNEST(Survey_Instance) as Survey_Instance,
   
GROUP BY
  Title,
  Description
```

Here´s how the schema of my source table looks like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Title",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Description",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Address",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "Address_Instance",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "Field1",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "name": "Field2",
            "type": "STRING"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Survey",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "Survey_Instance",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "Field1",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "name": "Field2",
            "type": "STRING"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

While mapping to the destination table, I rename the nested repeated records but that´s not causing any problems. I am wondering if I am overlooking something important and need some suggestions and advice. Basically an extra set of eyes to help me figure what I am doing wrong.
Would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explicit `JOIN`s in general.  In this case, use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
FROM source_table st LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(st.Survey) Survey
     ON 1=1 LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(Survey.Survey_Instance) Survey_Instance
     ON 1=1
```

Comment: Thank you, @Gordon. That helped but I have now gotten a lot of duplicate rows for all the fields which are not in `GROUP BY` clause. I have used `ON 1=1 LEFT JOIN` after each un nesting but what´s the difference between `LEFT JOIN ON 1=1 ` and `1=1`?

Comment: @MoirK . . . Your `GROUP BY` should return one row per title and description.  This answers the question you have asked here about why certain data is dropped out and how to prevent that.  You might want to ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.  Perhaps judicious use of `DISTINCT` would help solve your problem.